# Collapsing a column to yes/no on query

Tags: postgresql, case

I have a table with two columns `name` and `value`.

There are many rows with the same name, but with different values.

I want to create a function that returns a table with 2 columns.  The first column is the `name` and the second is a character, either `yes` or `no`, which refers to whether a name has a specific value or not.

If a name  has the specific value at least at one of its values to return yes and if it does not have the specific value to return no.

---

With the answers so far, I return the same name many times with the corresponding values like

('BOB'-'NO','BOB'-'NO','BOB'-'NO','BOB'-'NO','BOB'-'YES','JAME'-'NO','JAME'-'NO','JAME'-'NO','JAME'-'NO','JAME'-'NO') for example.

I want to return a table like that:

('BOB'-'YES','JAME'-'NO')

because bob has a specific value that I want at least one time at his values and JAME has not the specific value in a row.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: Table definition, sample values, desired result, Postgres version would make this more instructive.

Answer (score 4):

Here are three simple methods to do it,

1. **Returning `bool`**: Just use a simple `CASE` statement.

   ```
   SELECT name, CASE WHEN value = 'foo' THEN true ELSE false END
   FROM table;
   ```
2. **Returning `bool` compact:** You can actually make it more terse, so long as value is `NOT NULL`. That `CASE` statement is essentially equal to

   ```
   SELECT name, value = 'foo'
   FROM table;
   ```

   If `value` is ever null though you'll get `null` rather than `false`.
3. **Returning `text`**: If you insist on `yes` and `no` instead (I wouldn't do that), you can use strings instead of the special-made boolean type (there is no more compact syntax to write this).

   ```
   SELECT name, CASE WHEN value = 'foo' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
   FROM table;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> If a name has the specific value at least at one of its values to
>   return yes and if it does not have the specific value to return no.

You left room for interpretation, but this seems to be what you are after:

```
SELECT name, bool_or(value = 'specific_value') AS has_specific_value
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY name;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

> `bool_or(expression)` ... true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false.

You get *one* row per distinct `name` and a flag indicating whether the name has the given value in at least one of its rows.

You might want to add `count(*)` to also get the number of rows per `name`.
`count(*) FILTER (WHERE value = 'specific_value')` to get the count of *matching* rows would only make sense where there *can* be multiple matches, i.e. no `UNIQUE` constraint on `(name, value)` or similar - *"but with different values"* seems to indicate as much.
And maybe append `ORDER BY ...`