# How to do this binary appearance analysis

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a table named `results`:

```
integer: id
json: websites
```

An example of `websites` column is:

`[{"url": "http://google.com"}, {"url": "http://example.com"}]`

What I want to do is generate a binary appearance chart, where it shows a `1` or a `0` depending on if ANY url in the JSON blob is contained within another set.

All the possibilities are on columns, and all the `results` are as rows.

```
result_id | wikipedia.org | google.com | example.com
10         1               1            1
11         0               1            0
12         0               0            0
13         1               0            0
```

- For it to return `1`, ANY url in the JSON array object (with key `->>{'url'}`) must match the domain
- The URLs are full urls so ideally I would like to use regex to check if its a match (i can't do a full string match because I only care about the HOST of the URL). I'm thinking something like `/https?:\/\/(example\.com)(/|?|$)/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming data type `jsonb` and current Postgres 10.

Exact matches are simpler, since you can use the built-in [`jsonb` contains operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT id
     , (websites @> '[{"url": "http://wikipedia.org"}]')::int AS "wikipedia.org"
     , (websites @> '[{"url": "http://google.com"}]'   )::int AS "google.com"
     , (websites @> '[{"url": "http://example.com"}]'  )::int AS "example.com"
FROM   results
ORDER  BY id;
```

The cast to integer only to meet your desired form of `1`/`0`. Or omit the cast and just use the boolean `t`/`f` instead.

Pattern matching is more sophisticated, since there is no direct `jsonb` operator:

```
SELECT id
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE url ~ '^https?://wikipedia\.org\M') AS "wikipedia.org"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE url ~ '^https?://google\.com\M')    AS "google.com"
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE url ~ '^https?://example\.com\M')   AS "example.com"
FROM   results r
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT elem->>'url' AS url
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(r.websites) w(elem)
   ) w ON true
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6f4c07f30794a9a0f1d29c3053deab62)*

Replace `count(*) FILTER ...` with `bool_or(url ~ '^https?://wikipedia\.org\M')` etc. if URLs are never contained more than once and/or you are not interested in the actual count.

Related:

- [Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/search-for-nested-values-in-jsonb-array-with-greater-operator/202761#202761)
- [Indexed range comparison of array key's value in row inside JSONB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202617/indexed-range-comparison-of-array-keys-value-in-row-inside-jsonb/202729#202729)
- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)
- [Collapsing a column to yes/no on query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205185/collapsing-a-column-to-yes-no-on-query/205228#205228)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Dang this is super gangster.... I have never heard of a Left Join Lateral before. 

Comment: This answer is nuts, thank you. I learn so much here

Comment: @Tallboy: I added one more link with more about `LATERAL`.