# Update dynamic column names using keys from jsonb argument

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, update, json, dynamic-sql

I'd like to write a generic procedure for Postgres 12 that updates a table's columns depending on what data is supplied in a `jsonb` argument. It could be done in application logic instead of course, but I'm trying to push as much code down into the db layer as possible.

This is the kind of thing I naively hoped might work:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE record_event(
  foo_arg integer,
  name_arg text,
  data_arg jsonb,
  occurred_at_arg timestamptz
)
AS $$
DECLARE column_name text;
BEGIN
  -- This part is incidental:
  INSERT INTO foo_event(foo, name, data, occurred_at)
    VALUES(foo_arg, name_arg, data_arg, occurred_at_arg);

  -- This is the part I'm struggling with:
  FOR column_name IN (SELECT * FROM jsonb_object_keys(data_arg)) LOOP
    PREPARE update_query(text, text, integer) AS
      UPDATE foo SET $1 = $2 WHERE id = $3;
    EXECUTE update_query(column_name, data_arg->>column_name, foo_arg);
  END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But pg doesn't like `$1` in that position:

```
psql:src/db/migrations/foo/up.sql:43: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 15:       UPDATE foo SET $1 = $2 WHERE id = $3;
```

I also noticed there is a `json_populate_record()` function which seems like it should be helpful here, but I don't really understand how to apply it to my situation from the documentation.

Does what I'm trying to do make sense and is something like it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is too dynamic for `json_populate_record()`: it takes a record type which you don't know (nor have) at the time of calling.

#### `PROCEDURE` calling `UPDATE` for each JSON key

Proof of concept to show what did not work in your attempt.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE record_event (foo_arg int
                             , name_arg text
                             , data_arg jsonb
                             , occurred_at_arg timestamptz)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   column_name text;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO foo_event
        (foo    , name    , data    , occurred_at)
   VALUES(foo_arg, name_arg, data_arg, occurred_at_arg);

   -- works, but inefficiently:
   FOR column_name IN 
      SELECT * FROM jsonb_object_keys(data_arg)
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('UPDATE foo SET %I = $1 WHERE id = $2', column_name)
      USING data_arg->>column_name, foo_arg;
   END LOOP;
END
$proc$;
```

Call:

```
CALL record_event(1, 'name_arg', '{"col1":"val1","CoL2":"val2"}', now());
```

Column names cannot be dynamic, so format the query (with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for convenience) and use `EXECUTE`. But *values* are better provided with the `USING` clause.

Note the format specifier `%I`, but the parameters `$1` and `$2` refer to values provided by the `USING` clause (not to function parameters!).

But I would ***not*** use it. Multiple `UPDATE` commands are pretty inefficient. Instead use a ...

#### Function with a single `UPDATE`

Should be much more efficient.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_event(foo_arg int
                                      , name_arg text
                                      , data_arg jsonb
                                      , occurred_at_arg timestamptz)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO foo_event
          (foo    , name    , data    , occurred_at)
   VALUES (foo_arg, name_arg, data_arg, occurred_at_arg);

   SELECT INTO _sql
          'UPDATE foo SET '
       || string_agg(format('%I = %L', key, value), ', ')
       || ' WHERE id = ' || foo_arg
   FROM   jsonb_each_text(data_arg);

   IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql; -- uncomment instead of EXECUTE to debug
      EXECUTE _sql;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT record_event(1, 'name_arg', '{"col1":"val1","CoL2":"val2"}', now());
```

We *could* pass values to `EXECUTE` with another `USING` clause. But simply concatenate the whole command for convenience.

Using a `FUNCTION` as there is nothing that would require a `PROCEDURE` (new since Postgres 11). Would work as procedure too, though.

As always, properly quote identifiers and values to defend against possible SQL injection. I only dare to concatenate `foo_arg` directly, as an `integer` value is safe in this regard and works as unquoted numeric literal.

Note that column names are treated case-sensitively.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

Related:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries)
- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118418/when-to-use-stored-procedure-user-defined-function/118419#118419)
- [How to create a table dynamically based on json data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206082/how-to-create-a-table-dynamically-based-on-json-data)