# PostgreSQL: Insert dynamic columns and values from jsonb argument

Tags: postgresql, insert, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, jsonb

This question relates to [Update dynamic column names using keys from jsonb argument](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252531) and my code is based on the answer provided there by https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter

I'm trying to write a generic function that inserts data into a table with multiple data types from a jsonb record. How can I dynamically cast each value to the data type for the respective column?

I'm using PostgreSQL version 15.2

A typical call to this function would be:

```
json_data = '{
    "text_field": "Some text",
    "numeric_field": 17,
    "datetime_field": "2023-04-24 11:06:50.36758-04",
    "boolean_field": true
}'

SELECT * FROM insert_jsonb('schema_name', 'table_name', json_data);
```

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_from_jsonb(
    sch_name text,
    tbl_name text,
    js jsonb,
    out new_id uuid;
) AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _sql text;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO _sql
        'INSERT INTO ' || sch_name || '.' || tbl_name || ' ('
        || string_agg(format('%I', key), ', ') || ') VALUES ('
        || string_agg(format('%L', value), ', ') || ')' -- < how can I cast each value?
        || ' RETURNING uuid'
    FROM jsonb_each_text(js);

    IF _sql IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql; -- uncomment for debugging
        EXECUTE _sql INTO new_id;  -- comment out for debugging
    END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concatenate values as (untyped) **string literals** into the query string, so you don't need to add an explicit cast. Postgres will coerce each value with an assignment cast to the data type of the target column **automatically**. (Must be valid for the type, of course. Else you get an error. But an explicit cast wouldn't get you the same result.)

Your posted function works as is. I would only suggest an outer `format()` to tidy up:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_from_jsonb(sch_name text
                                           , tbl_name text
                                           , js jsonb
                                           , OUT new_id uuid)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
      format('INSERT INTO %I.%I (%s) VALUES (%s) RETURNING uuid'
           , sch_name, tbl_name
           , string_agg(format('%I', key), ', ')
           , string_agg(format('%L', value), ', ')  -- < no explicit cast needed
            )
   FROM   jsonb_each_text(js);

   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      RAISE WARNING '%', 'Your text here';
   ELSE
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;    -- uncomment for debugging
      EXECUTE _sql INTO new_id;  -- comment out for debugging
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: Thank you Erwin, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See the updated insert function in Erwin's answer. I decided to merge the insert with the update function from the related question: [Update dynamic column names using keys from jsonb argument](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252531). This function updates an existing record if the "id" is provided, or generates a new UUID and inserts a new record if no "id" is provided. Either way returns the resource ID.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_from_jsonb(
    sch_name text,
    tbl_name text,
    js jsonb,
    out res_id uuid)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    new_js jsonb;
    _sql text;
BEGIN
    SELECT (js ->> 'id')::uuid INTO res_id;
    IF res_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        new_js := js - 'id';
        SELECT INTO _sql
            format('UPDATE %I.%I SET %s WHERE id = %L',
                sch_name, tbl_name,
                string_agg(format('%I = %L', key, value), ', '),
                res_id
            )
        FROM jsonb_each_text(new_js);
    ELSE
        res_id := gen_random_uuid();
        new_js := js || jsonb_build_object('id', res_id);
        SELECT INTO _sql
            format('INSERT INTO %I.%I (%s) VALUES (%s)',
                sch_name, tbl_name,
                string_agg(format('%I', key), ', '),
                string_agg(format('%L', value), ', ')
            )
        FROM jsonb_each_text(new_js);
    END IF;

    IF _sql IS NULL THEN
        RAISE WARNING 'No sql for %I.%I on %s', sch_name, tbl_name, js;
    ELSE
        -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql; -- uncomment for debugging
        EXECUTE _sql;  -- comment out for debugging
    END IF;
END
$func$;
```